# Need help in translation for a letter written to my grandfather in esperanto

Tags: translation

I have tried google translate, but i will be greatful if someone can help improve the translation. Thank you :)

[image]

> Oni Korespondas en Esperanto       Kairo, 16 Marto 1939.
>
> Sinjoro Sajed Ali Multanano, Kalkuto.
>
> Mia kara amiko, antaŭ unu monato mi ricevis vian ŝatatan leteron kiun
> sekvis=post unu semajno=la teo-pakaĵo. Koncerne la kvaliton de la teo
> ĝi ne estas bona tamesn trinkebla sed ne gravas, mi trinkados ĝian
> sukon ĝis kiam ĝi gustos al mi, kaj poste, mi faros cigaredojn el ĝi
> por regali miajn konatojn. Tio estas la plej ne komprenebla ke la
> komercisto kalkuta kalkulis du anaojn pli por la afranko de la pakaĵo
> ol li efektive afrankis. La kaira poŝto pagigis per mi 12 piastrojn,t?e. 1
> Rupio 12 anaoj, nome 9 piastrojn por la dogano kaj 3 piastrojn al la
> poŝto pro la ne sufiĉa afranko.
>
> Nun mi petas vin sendl al mi alion; hindoj generale diras ke la
> kolza oleo, sarsoun-ka-tel. Hinde estas tre bona konservilo de haroj
> kontrau la blankigo, mi ankaŭ uzis tiun oleon dum mia restado en
> Hindujo. Mi petas bonvolu tuj sendi al mi duon-litron da ĝi.  Ĝi povas
> esti parfumita, nur estu tre atenta ĉar ĉi tiun oleon oni ofte falsigas
> per alia malplikara oleo. Ankaŭ bonvolu atente enpaki ĝin ke dum la
> transporto ĝi ne estu difektebla. Mi pensas ke stanita ferlada vazo
> estas preferinda ol vitra.
>
> Mi intencas sendi al vi belegan libron tre volumenan 16 sur23
> centrimetroj 500 paĝa, titolita Jarmiloj Pasas, tiu-ĉi libro estas
> mirinda verkaĵo en bonega stilo verkita originale en Esperanto. Ĝi
> estas iom kara sed tre interesa kaj scienca traktanta la universalan
> historion, la evoluon de la unu ĉela besteto ĝis la nuna civilizita
> homo, pri religioj, politiko ktp. Mi rekomendas al vi ĉi tiun libron
> ĉar konas vin kaj scias ke vi estas sciencema.
>
> Koncerne la priskribon de la irano bonvolu iom atendi.
>
> kun sincera saluto
>
> Demetrio Fedorĉak
>
> Mansurah
>
> Poŝte Restanta
>
> Egiptujo

Translation as per Google Translate

> One is answered in Esperanto Kairo, March 16, 1939
>
> Mr. Sajed Ali Multanano, Kalkuta,
>
> My dear friend, one month ago I received your satellite letter that
> followed one week after a week = the tea pakajo. In terms of the
> quality of the tea, it is not good enough to drink but it does not
> matter, I will drink its sugar when it boils to me, and then I will
> make cigarettes of it to regain my acquaintances. This is the most
> understandable that the retailer has calculated two ducks more for the
> garlic olli actually cut off. The Kaira post has paid 12 pies with me.
> I Rupio 12 ducks, 9 piasters for the customs and 3 piasters to the
> post due to the not enough thread.
>
> No one asks me to send me an attachment; Hindus generally says that
> the collar oil, sarsoun-ka-tel. Hinde is a very good hair keeper
> against the whitening, I also used this oil while staying in India. I
> beg you to send me a half-liter of goodbye. It can be perfumed but be
> very attentive when this oil is often falsified by other lesser oil.
> Also, be careful to pack it at all times that during transport it may
> not be defective. I think that a stanita forage vessel is preferable
> than vitra.
>
> I intend to send you a beautiful book very large I6 on23 centimeters
> 500 pounds, titled Millennium Passes, this is a wonderful writing in
> an excellent style originally written in Esperanto. It is a bit dear
> to the world's interesting and scientific interest in the history of
> the world, the evolution of the one target animal by the current
> civilized people, religions, politics, etc. I recommend this book to
> you since you know and know that you are scientifically.
>
> Regarding the Iranian description, please wait a little.
>
> with sincere greeting Demetrio Fedorcak Mansurah Later remaining Egypt

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE]! Please note that this is a questions-and-answers (Q&A) community, not a translation service. It's OK to ask for translations of individual words or phrases, or even a single sentence in context, but requesting translations of complete texts isn't what this site is for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to request a translation of a letter's complete text and/or a review of a (google-translate-generated) machine translation of that text. This is out-of-scope of a Q&A site like [esperanto.SE].

Comment: If you'd like to ask about a specific aspect of the translation, feel free to [edit] your question accordingly! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt at a translation:

> *One makes correspondence in Esperanto.*
>
> Cairo, 16th March 1939.
>
> Mr. Sajed Ali Multanano, Calcutta.
>
> My dear friend, a month ago I received your much appreciated letter which was followed – a week later – by the tea package. About the quality of the tea, it is not good, however it is drinkable, but it doesn’t matter, I will keep drinking its juice until it is tasty to me, and afterwards, I will make cigarettes out of it to treat my acquaintances. That is the most incomprehensible thing that the [shopkeeper/businessman] in Calcutta calculated two annas more for the postage of the package than he actually stamped. The postal service in Cairo made me pay 12 piastres there [a letter seems to be missing so I’m not sure of the last word]. 1 rupee and 12 annas, in other words 9 piastres for the customs officer and 3 piastres to the post office because of the insufficient postage.
>
> Now I ask you to send me something else; [Indians/Hindus] generally say that the colza oil, “sarsoun-ka -tel” [?] in Hindi, is a very good tool for protecting hair against whitening, I also used that oil during my stay in India. Please kindly send me a half litre of it straight away. It can be perfumed, just be very careful because people often fake this oil with another cheaper oil. Also please pack it carefully so that it won’t be possible to damage it in transport. I think a tin can would be preferable to glass.
>
> I am intending to send you a very large, beautiful book, 16x23cm, 500 pages, called Millenniums Pass, this book is an amazing work in an excellent style, written originally in Esperanto. It’s a bit expensive but very interesting and scientific, covering universal history, the evolution of the single-celled creature until the current civilised man, religion, politics etc. I recommend this book to you because I know you and know that you are scientifically minded.
>
> About the description of Iran, please wait a while.
>
> With sincere greetings,
>
> Demetrio Fedorĉak
>
> Mansurah [?]
>
> Post-ly remaining,
>
> Egypt

Thank you for sharing this very interesting letter with us.

Comment: I think, in the first sentence it should be *a week later* instead of *a month later* . [some coin] is [anna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_rupee#Decimalisation) or annas. 16 annas = 1 rupee.

Comment: @Olafant Thanks for the suggestions. I’ve edited the answer.

Comment: "Mansurah" probably refers to [Mansoura, Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansoura%2C_Egypt) and "Poŝte Restanta" probably refers to [Poste restante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante), which is how the addressee would reply to the author of the letter.

Comment: Even my mother didnt know that my grandfather knew Esperanto. Thanks a lot for your help. This means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am a researcher at the University of Cambridge working on Esperanto. I found this letter extremely intriguing and was wondering if you would like to chat more on its origins or whether there are others?

Please feel free to get in touch at
bb627@cam.ac.uk
OR bipashabster@gmail.com